# How I can use Windows Phone and Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, windows-phone-8

I'm new with Selenium and I need use Selenium WebDriver with Windows Phone. I follow this link https://winphonewebdriver.codeplex.com/.

When I click to "StartWindowsPhoneDriver.cmd" my emulator is working nice with a blank page but I don't know how to insert C# code for control it.

Anyone can help and give me an example (or a link with an example) please ?

Best regards,

Xialuna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in your MainPage.xaml.cs Constructor:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://______:______"), DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://winphonewebdriver.codeplex.com/");
```

What I read now is that you must get the IP Adress from the **StartWindowsPhoneDriver.cmd** thats print in the console. Put it when you are Initializing RemoteWebDriver and must work.

Greetings!

Comment: Ho I didn't take the IP Adress and now after few seconds my emulator works ! Thanks :)